# HttpSession does not return retrieve value when request is made from angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, servlets, httpsession

Hi I have saved captcha code which is generated through a servlet in HttpSession and send it to the Angular component. Now when user send back the captcha which he sees there i am not able to compare it to the one in the HttpSession because it comes as null.

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public GenericResponse registerNewUserAccount(@RequestBody UserVO user,
Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    if (user.getCaptchaResponse() != null ) {
        if (user.getCaptchaResponse().equals(request.getAttribute("captcha"))) {
        ...
        } else {
        ...
        }
}
else {
        ...
} }
```

Seeting session as:

public class CaptchServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String captchaStr = "";
    captchaStr = CaptchUtility.generateCaptchaTextMethod2(6);
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("captcha", captchaStr);
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(cpimg, FILE_TYPE, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

}

in controller session.getAttribute("captcha") is null.

Answer (score 0):

add `{withCredentials: true}` to angular calls

```js
this.http.get(someUrl, {withCredentials: true})
```

this will send cookies with the request and that is the most probable reason of your problem that cookies are not sent